# Can't open terminal from anaconda (a.tool error)

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, conda, macos-catalina

I recently updated to Catalina 10.15.1, and since I've updated I'm unable to update packages in Anaconda via Navigator.

I've tried running `bash -c "conda init zsh"` to update the **.zshrc** file after completely **uninstalling all anaconda files** and **reinstalling Anaconda using the command line** Anaconda3-2019.10 .sh installer.

But it still appears I'm unable to update or even see updatable files from the navigator, and whenever I attempt to open terminal from the base environment or any virtual environment, the terminal screen pops up with the following exception error:

```
/Users/myname/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;                               

(base) myname@Lee-iMac ~ % /Users/leegary/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;

/Users/myname/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

/Users/myname/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: `bash --init-file <(echo "source activate /Users/leegary/anaconda3;")'



[Process completed]
```

Executing this a.tool file in the navigator folder I received the same error. The contents of this file are in the code below:

```
bash --init-file <(echo "source activate /Users/leegary/anaconda3;")
```